# eTA for Canada - does the space in the passport number matter?

Tags: canada, eta

I'm extremely stressed because I put a space in the passport number for my ETA.

The space is present in the passport number in the right upper corner of the passport personal information page, but not in the code at the bottom. It divides the letters and numbers of the passport n.

My eTA was accepted. I am traveling tomorrow.

Should I reapply??

Comment: *It divides the letters and numbers of the passport n.* ??

Answer (score 7):

As your eTA was accepted I would not be too worried. In my experience, Canada customs are pretty relaxed: I did not even get any problems when they forgot to put an entry stamp into my passport. Although I do not know whether your passport number is supposed to contain a space, I do not think you will run into any problems as the space is clearly visible in your passport.

Comment: Customs it not the issue here.  The eTA is electronically verified at check-in.  If you don't have one, you're not boarding the plane...

Answer (score 4):

My experience:
My passport number does contain a space which does not show up in the MRZ though.
I applied for the ETA using the passport number with the space. 
I had no issues getting into Canada (Vancouver).

Comment: Im sure the system will remove spaces in the back end if people put them in

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reapply. You didn't specify the country issuing your passport but it doesn't matter: every country uses a very rigid format which doesn't allow for misunderstandings. It is never possible to have one passport with `AB 123` and another with `A B123` for the number so when they match the eTA with your passport, there's no problem from a space. For example, here's an unofficial list of [EU passport numbers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/eu-passport-number) and more can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/what-the-sensitive-information-types-look-for). These documents might be unofficial but they are Microsoft security compliance documents not just some random travel blogger so it's fairly reliable. As far as I can see only Austria allows a space in their numbers and the format, again, is rigid: one letter, optional space, seven digits. Whether you write it out or not, there is no ambiguity. Most countries will do zero, one or two letters followed by all digits. I suspect you put a space between your letter(s) and the digits, again, that's no problem.